# Binding 2 images inside a FlipView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, flipview

I have the same question asked here:
[Image overlay in a flipview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583816/image-overlay-in-a-flipview)

Except, I have binded the `FlipView.ItemTemplate` to a `UserControl` having 2 images.
To be able to access the binded `ImageSource` from the MainPage.xaml.cs, I created 2 global variables in App.xaml.cs:

```
public static ImageSource Image1 { get; set; }
public static ImageSource Image2 { get; set; }

public static new App Current
{
    get { return Application.Current as App; }
}
```

I can set the first image in this way:

```
flipView.Items.Add(new Uri(BaseUri, Images[0]));
```

But if I bind the images in this way, nothing is displayed even the flipView:

```
App.Image1 = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Images/page0.jpg"));
```

How should I bind them in a way they get generated automatically & consecutively from an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new class:

```
public class MyImage
{
     public ImageSource Image1 { get; set; }
     public ImageSource Image2 { get; set; }
}
```

in your page, you have to load your images as `List<MyImage>`, (if index is odd, myImage.Image1 = yourImage, else myImage.Image2 = yourImage)

then, in your user control, bind your images to Image1 and Image2, and set the ItemsSource of your flip to the `List<MyImage>`